# SQL injection query for enumerating available tables in databases

Tags: mysql, sql, database, security, sql-injection

We have an exercise and are struggling to come up with a sql injection to find more data from the database in mySQL.

Here is how far we have got:
[mySQL webpage result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B8iWT.png)

In the above picture you can see we have managed to get the database to divulge the userid, user and passwd values.

To achieve this we have typed:
`admin' --`
in the login box

Then:
`' union select table_name from information_schema.tables --`
in the password box

However, this is not the entire goal of the exercise. We must discover the databases and tables that are available.
We are unsure why the response is not taking into account our query `union select table_name from information_schema.tables`.

Here is an example of what the response is if nothing is typed in either login or password box:
[default mySQL webpage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3JhaZ.png)

Our tasks:

1. enumerate available tables in the database
2. find username with userid of 3 (done - right?)
3. find a table containing md5 hashes

Could someone point us in the right direction?

Why isnt our `select table_name from information_schema.tables` working?

UPDATE: we managed to get 238 rows returned after restructuring our initial query in the first login box to:

```
admin’ union select table_name,2,3 from information_schema.tables -- -
```

The fix: the amount of columns have to match between first select query and union select query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably have to put the entire injection in the username box. At the moment the `--` after the `admin'` in the login input is commenting the rest of the query.

i.e. The login box should contain `admin' UNION SELECT table_name FROM information_schema.tables --`

You may need to select padding columns from `information_schema.tables` as there is no way to tell how many columns the `users` table has.

Comment: what would padding columns look like? just table_name,2,3,4... until the right number is achieved?
also, we put the entire injection in the username box however nothing is returned at all...

Comment: we have tried ...table_name,2,3 from... and now have 238 rows returned!

Comment: Then you're done, right? Surely you can just expand my answer to `UNION SELECT` anything you want from any table, as long as you add padding columns in the same manner.

Comment: We found a table with name "sql_lab_tokens", so we did query: "admin' union select column_name,2,3 from information_schema.columns where table_nam = 'sql_lab_tokens' -- -".

This gave us a list of the column names. We now wanted to find out the data within. So we tried this query: "admin' union select * from sql_lab_tokens -- -" but this did not work. 

We would like to know the data in this sql_lab_tokens table...

Comment: You're on the right track, but I'm not going to do all your homework for you. Instead, here's some questions that should lead you where you need to go.

1. Why did I tell you to add padding columns to your query? 
2. Why does your injection only work when you add `,2, 3`?
3. Does this tell you anything about the Users table?
4. What is the difference between `admin' union select table_name,2,3 from information_schema.tables --` and `admin' union select * from sql_lab_tokens`? Why does the first one work and the second one doesn't?
5. How can you modify your second query to make it work?

Comment: i see what you are saying however i did modify the select 1,2,3 from sql_lab_tokens, but that didnt work either. the same with 1,2. i will attempt a join

Comment: id,sql_lab_md5_passwd,3 worked! thanks for your assistance